# Android's GeoCoder class is giving timeout error

Tags: android, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I was getting

> "Timed out waiting for response from server"

Error in GeoCoder class in android.location package.
This issue persisted for more than 24 hours. and suddenly started working.

These are the logs.

> 1)while getting address from lat,Long
>
> 01-15 16:01:41.213 2507-2558 W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Timed
>   out waiting for response from server 01-15 16:01:41.238 2507-2558
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
>
> 2)Getting lat long from Address is also failing with timeout. 01-15
>   16:19:22.496 2507-2553/com.nearfox.android W/System.err:
>   java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting for response from server 01-15
>   16:19:22.603 2507-2517 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 74.882ms
>   01-15 16:19:22.608 2507-2553 W/System.err:     at
>   android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:178)

Shall we start using Maps api from google or continue with this one??

Comment: what caused the problem? some internet connection issue? Fix the problem, probably the code will work

Comment: You will see lot of posts where this issue is mentioned. The best solution is you directly use map's geocode apis.

Comment: @Gavriel no it was not internet issue. every apis were working fine. even geocoder working fine the day before one day.

Comment: @HardikTrivedi yes i am thinking to use it as a back up plan but GeoCoder does not have any quota limit and Map apis have..